# Django create_or_update(), unique_together, unique, and primary

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm still trying to fully understand Django models, let's say I have the following model:

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(amx_length=255, unique=True)

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
    unique_together = ('manufacturer', 'name')
```

And I run the following commands:

```
honda = Manufacturer.objects.get(name='Honda') #Let's assume this object already exists
car = Car.objects.get_or_create(name='Honda Accord', color='Red', manufacturer=honda)
car = Car.objects.get_or_create(name='Honda Accord', color='Green', manufacturer=honda)
```

Will Django simply update the existing car to change the color from Red to Green? Or will issues arise because I don't have a `primary_key` set?

Also, does it matter if I use `primary_key` or `unique` or are they the same? I'm using a mySQL backend if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django automatically sets a primary key field called `id` unless you specify one yourself. So your `Car` model will already have an `id` field. It's on the base model class that your model inherits.

In your example, you haven't specified the `defaults` argument of the `get_or_create()` method, so Django will only attempt to retrieve an object with the values you've passed in via a get call: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create

unique constraints can be specified on a field regardless if it's an AutoField or not. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#unique for more specific information.

Comment: What am I missing in the get_or_create() I gave all 3 fields values? And does this mean a duplicate will be created, or changed?

Comment: If you look at the docs, it states that unless you supply the optional parameter `defaults`, Django will pass the values given in `get_or_create` to be used in a `.get()` lookup. Django will not try to create a model instance unless you pass in `defaults={'<field>': 'value', ...}` in addition to your values to get the model by.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood that when I read the docs originally, I'll read up

Comment: You're welcome. One of the things that makes Django such a great framework is its documentation. It's some of the best I've ever seen, but it's also important to get familiar with the source code too.

Comment: Ahh, I was getting `update_or_create` and `get_or_create` mixed up. Thanks again